# Search using spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm a beginner in spring mvc and hibernate. I want to ask about the best searching method to search mysql database, especially in case of hibernate mapping among two or more tables. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Its a wider question. So can you please be specific or particular scenario or business to choose the mechanism or technologies.

Comment: Sure :) I have three tables.I have associated them using hibernate mapping. Now what I want to do is searching the data using any property of these three tables so that I can return a list of data and populate my jsp page with the list.

Comment: Thanks. One more question.Can you specify the maximum data size or number of records that you might get in response once if you getting it from a query?

Comment: spring data could be a nice solution

Comment: Actually I'm now working with small scale data size. So, minimum number record will be around 10. But it can be more depending upon the number of related records in the database.

Comment: Kindly go through the basics of hibernate, how to get the response for a straight forward query into List object and then try to apply filter on top of that.

Comment: Thanks @SASIKUMARS for your kind advice.